# Adding private member variable causes namespace to go missing in C# assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

This may be the most bizarre error I've ever encountered using .NET/C# - adding a private member variable of a type from an external assembly apparently causes my own namespace to go missing.

I have two projects in a solution:

- UI
- Core

`UI` contains a project reference to `Core`.

`Core` contains a reference to the `TwainDotNet.dll` version TwainDotNet-1.0-12-03-2011 from http://code.google.com/p/twaindotnet/

Inside of my `Core` project, adding the below code (and this is all of it!) is sufficient to cause the problem:

```
using TwainDotNet;

namespace Core
{
    public class TwainMonitor 
    {
        private Twain _twain; //comment this field out, and
                              //everything builds fine.
    }
}
```

The symptoms are that `Core` builds fine.  But `UI` complains that:

```
The type or namespace name 'Core' could not be found (are you missing 
a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Why on earth would adding a private member variable of a type from an external assembly cause my own namespace to go missing in action?

Comment: What happens if you add the private field and reference this external DLL at `UI`?

Comment: Are you changing the version number when you rebuild the assembly?

Comment: Just to rule out occasional goofiness that VS sometimes exhibits, have you tried deleting the bin and obj folders and recompiling?

Comment: Also try fully qualifying the `Twain` variable type. Could be result of an ambiguous namespace?

Comment: @hatchet - yep I am using mercurial and have even done hg purge --all as well as a clean clone and then re-adding the problematic code.

Comment: @Abe Miessler - I am not doing anything (at least intentionally) with the version number.

Comment: As @Nick mentioned it could be colliding namespaces. Sometimes it's not all that obvious. It may only be a partial collision, but it's enough for the compiler not to know which class to use.

Comment: @Nick - does not appear to be a namespace collision.  Fully qualifying has no affect, and I don't define anything myself in a TwainDotNet namespace.

Comment: @Andre Calil - Oddly enough, the `UI` project doesn't find TwainDotNet namespace when I put the example code in the `UI` project even when I ensure I have the assembly referenced (and VS autocomplete know the namespace is there).

Comment: In that case another thing to try is placing the `using TwainDotNet;` inside the namespace declaration.

Comment: @Nick - moving the `using TwainDotNet;` inside of the namespace declaration has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not be certain that this is infact your issue, but I have experienced these symptoms before when referencing things targetting the **Full** framework profile from project targetting a **Client** framework profile.

What I would try, is making sure that you are targetting the .Net 4 Full profile and **NOT** the client profile in your project properties for both of your projects.

Comment: Thank you! My `UI` project was targeting Client Profile - setting everything to use the Full profile did the trick.